# One MPMoviePlayerController instance can buffer two video resources (URL) at the same time?

Tags: iphone, buffer, mpmovieplayercontroller

I hope a player can buffer two movies at the same time so that i can play the first movie and the other buffering at the same time .if the first one played finished ,the second can continue to play Immediately。

One MPMoviePlayerController instance can buffer two video resources (URL) at the same time?????

hope your ideas,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Two instances of MPMoviePlayerController would do what you want.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *a = [MPMoviePlayerController initWithContentsOfURL:/*...*/];
MPMoviePlayerController *b = [MPMoviePlayerController initWithContentsOfURL:/*...*/];
```

Comment: Thanks，i tried it ,but is unsuccessful .
i used two threads for two MPMoviePlayerViewController's instances ，one used for playing the first video resources,the other for buffering the second video resources,but when i played the first movie a bit seconds，it stop(not finished),then the second movie loading and continue to play.i hope when the first finished ,then the second plays, no time interval.